# Receiving an exception and code failing when trying to delete a line from a .txt file using java

Tags: java, file, exception, delete-file, filewriter

I am trying to delete a specific line from my text file using java, My code is supposed to write the file to a temp file and skip writing the username (chosen to be deleted), it is then supposed to delete the original file and rename the new temp file to match the original. The following is my code:

```
 // remove a user
    public static void deleteUser() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println(
                "Are you sure you want to delete a user? WARNING this will permanently remove them from our database\nmeaning you won't be able to recover their user from our index.txt file. (y/n)");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        if (Objects.equals(answer, "y")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the exact username you would like to delete:");
            String username = input.nextLine();

            deleteUserFromFile(username, "index.txt", 1, " ");

            System.out.println("User deleted.");

        } else if (Objects.equals(answer, "n")) {
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("The answer provided can't be read. Please answer again using 'y' or 'n'.");
            deleteUser();
        }
    }

    // remove user function
    public static void deleteUserFromFile(String username, String filepath, int positionOfTerm, String delimiter) {
        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);

        String currentLine;
        String data[];

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filepath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data = currentLine.split(delimiter);
                if (!(data[positionOfTerm].equalsIgnoreCase(username))) {
                    pw.println(currentLine);
                }
            }

            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fr.close();
            br.close();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();

            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filepath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured.");
        }
    }
```

The catch of this code is being triggered and I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

For reference this is my index file:

```
6
0 Gromit
1 Gwendolyn
2 Le-Spiderman
3 Wallace
4 Batman
5 Superman
```

EDIT:
I have included e.printStackTrace(); as suggested and this is the error I received from it:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at Graph.deleteUserFromFile(Graph.java:239)
        at Graph.deleteUser(Graph.java:208)
        at Graph.menu(Graph.java:284)
        at Graph.main(Graph.java:302)
```

The following is the referenced code, 302:

```
        menu();
```

284:

```
        deleteUser();
```

208 (username here is collected using a scanner input):

```
deleteUserFromFile(username, "index.txt", 1, " ");
```

239:

```
if (!(data[positionOfTerm].equalsIgnoreCase(username))) {
```

EDIT 2:

```
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data = currentLine.split(delimiter);

                String numOfUsernamesInList = br.readLine(); // updating the username number counter at the top of the
                                                             // index file
                int newNumOfUsernamesInList = Integer.parseInt(numOfUsernamesInList) - 1;
                pw.println(String.valueOf(newNumOfUsernamesInList));

                if (data.length > positionOfTerm && !(data[positionOfTerm].equalsIgnoreCase(username))) {
                    pw.println(currentLine);
                }
            }
```

This is my attempt of getting the 6 shown in the index file to stay and update to a 5 when a username is deleted from the index file, the following is the error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 Gromit"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at Graph.deleteUserFromFile(Graph.java:242)
        at Graph.deleteUser(Graph.java:208)
        at Graph.menu(Graph.java:290)
        at Graph.main(Graph.java:308)
```

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()`is going to get you proper information

Comment: There's your problem: `System.out.println("An error occured.")`.  The exception object tells you what error occurred, but you ignore it and print unspecific text. `e.getMessage()` would be useful.

Comment: @Matt the actual problem is invisible, because your exception management is badly written. That exception contains at least __4__ useful pieces of info and you've tossed it all in the garbage! Type, Message, Trace, and Cause. The right approach is to remove all your try/catch stuff and declare your method to `throws IOException`. Note that your `main` method can (and usually should!) be declared to `throws Exception`.

Comment: @Matt once you fix that, the system will tell you exactly what went wrong. I'm guessing: The file is currently already open. Once you edit the question with the type, message, trace, and if present, cause - we'll know for sure.

Comment: @danglingelse please don't teach the new folks bad habits. `e.getMessage()` is still disregarding the trace, the cause, and the type, all of which are at least as useful and probably more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added in e.printStackTrace() and have posted the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[positionOfTerm]` on the first line of the file does not exist. You need to check the array length before.

```
if (data.length > positionOfTerm && !(data[positionOfTerm].equalsIgnoreCase(username))) {
```

Comment: Thank you this allows me to delete a username however it also now deletes the first line for some reason. Is there any way around this

Comment: I have edited my post with my attempt and the error which it gave me